# What is going on with this .iso file?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, iso

I am attempting to install the latest edition of Linux Mint on my 2013 MacBook Pro, but seem to have fallen at the first hurdle.

On going to https://linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=246 and selecting the torrent option, my laptop promptly downloads the .iso.torrent file, which I then renamed to linuxmint.iso using the mv command.

However, the `Etcher` app refuses to write the file to USB. On digging further, I tried to use `hdiutil` to convert the `.iso` to a `.img`, only to receive the error message:

`convert failed - image not recognized`

Another strange feature is that the file is only 37 KB in size, whereas the site suggests it should be 1.8 GB.

I hope I'm not missing something obvious here, but any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.torrent` file is intended for use with a BitTorrent client, which will use it to download the real ISO. If you don’t want to do that, scroll down the download page a bit, and choose one of the mirrors — that will give you a direct download of the ISO.

Comment: So it turns out I was missing something obvious: having never used torrenting of any kind before, all I can do is admit my cluelessness and thank you for your prompt and clear answer!